# cannot specify name of the download file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, csv

I am using Javascript to create a CSV file for user to download.

Until May 22nd, Chrome still downloaded the file with the name I specified. However, today I found that the files downloaded are named "download" and do not have the extension .csv.

This problem does not exist in Firefox!

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkm2b/2/) with sample Javascript:

```
var A = [['n','sqrt(n)']];  // initialize array of rows with header row as 1st item
for(var j=1;j<10;++j){ A.push([j, Math.sqrt(j)]) }
var csvRows = [];
for(var i=0,l=A.length; i<l; ++i){
    csvRows.push(A[i].join(','));   // unquoted CSV row
}
var csvString = csvRows.join("\n");

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href     = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8;base64,' + window.btoa(csvString);
a.target   = '_blank';
a.download = 'myFile.csv';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Comment: That's weird... Last time I tried this it worked just fine in Chrome too. I'll have a look at why this is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice work! This is a regression.

I just created another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PCU2/1), and filed a [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377317).

If you're interested, star it in the bug tracker.

```
<a href="/" download="my-downloaded-file.html" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

---

EDIT: It look like it depends on the URL. Absolute URLs work, as well as [objects URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL) (according to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376197).

Comment: The error report is not completely correct though. [only data-URIs don't work anymore](http://jsfiddle.net/Cf48L/).

Comment: I'm sorry, I take that back (also removed Google forums post). I'm sure I must have been looking at the wrong thing or something, but I thought it worked. I have no idea if I was just derping there (probably) or if it was something else, but you're right.

Comment: so...this is a bug in one of the chromium update right?

Comment: fwiw @PaulDraper jsfiddle working ok at chromium 31. _at_ Joeytje50 Both links at jsfiddle work ok at chromium 31. jsfiddle at original post work ok, too. Is issue with chrome/chromium 35+ ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314, yes hence "This is a regression".

Comment: @PaulDraper Interesting. retrieved chromium 34 and chrome 37. The file name appears to be related to `href` attribute? Have a simple web page that had to check following this Question and Answer. Similar scenario, a `.pdf` file for download or print. That web page had both `download` and `href` attribute with same name, i.e.g., `foo.pdf`. Worked ok at both chromium 34 and chrome 37. Went back to your jsfiddle and changed the `href` to same as `download`, works ok  http://jsfiddle.net/n6QTS/. Have not tried further adjustments; appears file name is listed when `download` and `href` is same ?

Comment: @PaulDraper yes, createObjectURL does work. Thank you!